# Why when we want to rotate matrix horizontal/vertical we divide the term by 2?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I tried to rotate matrix horizontal/vertical and couldn't understand how and after I searched here I found that everyone divide the term by 2 , I really wanna know why its so important that if I don't do it the matrix will stay just the same,
example that we divide the rows in 2:

```
int temp;
for (int i = 0 ; i < getRows() / 2 ; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < getColumns() ; j++)
    {
        temp = _matrixArray[i][j];
        _matrixArray[i][j] = _matrixArray[_matrixArray.length - 1 - i][j];
        _matrixArray[_matrixArray.length - 1 -i][j] = temp;
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Hoping that I properly understood your question, I can say that the reason is the next one: you read your data from the matrix simultaneously from two ways, left to right ( 0 to n/2) and right to left (n to n/2 + 1) and swap these two step by step ( 0 with n-1, 1 with n-2, ... , n-k with n-k+1), therefore, when you reach half of its size, you've swapped them all, meaning that you performed your rotation

Answer (score 1):

The code you've copied here does a vertical reflection by going through rows 0 ... [n/2] and swapping them with rows [n/2] ... n-1.  I've used brackets [] to indicate rounding down.  Do you see, then, that the loop only needs to go up to [n/2]?